# Are the concepts of call by name and pass by reference seperate concepts?

Tags: c#, scala, evaluation

In my head at least, I've always had a pretty good idea of value vs reference passing with respect to functions. I'm going through Scala though and it appears its concept of call by name, is related but its own distinct concept

For example in C# there exists the ref keyword, and in Scala there exists the call by name => operator.

It's my understanding that the ref keyword - roughly at least - serves to pass a pointer to a piece of data, rather than that piece of data itself. i.e. when used with an Integer datatype, if you modify the Integer inside the function, the Integer will be affected on the callee side as well.

Call by name on the hand describes an evaluation strategy where any expressions in an argument, will be delayed until the expressions are used inside the function.

Does my understanding seem correct? If so, is it just so happens that these concepts have related names, or am I not seeing part of the picture? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the concepts of call by name and pass by reference separate concepts?

Yes. These are separate concepts. Call-by-name is about *when* we evaluate; pass-by-reference is about *what* we pass.

**Call by name** means the function argument is evaluated each time the function uses it, not before the function receives it.

**Call by value** (aka pass by value) means

- the function argument is evaluated before the function receives it, and
- "the resulting value is bound to the corresponding variable in the function."

**Call by reference** (aka pass by reference) means the function receives "an implicit reference to a variable... rather than a copy of its value."

Whereas call by name is a non-strict evaluation strategy, call by value and call by reference are two different strict (eager) evaluation strategies.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy